# Changing screens in Python without Screen Manager Class

Tags: python, kivy, screen

I'm using gestures in all of my screens, and I cannot use a screen manager class to manage my screens, or so I believe. I can navigate the .kv file by using `manger.current = 'some_screeen'` but cannot in the .py file.

I've been trying `Runner().ids.manager.current = 'some_screen'` in the .py file but it doesn't work. There isn't even an error thrown. The screen doesn't change at all.

Essential Code (for the sake of brevity):

```
class Runner(gesture.GestureBox):
    pass

MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Runner()
```

Then in the KV file, I'm creating the screen manager.

```
<Runner>:
    ScreenManager:
        id: manager

        Screen:
            name: 'main_screen'
            Button:
                on_press:
                    manager.current = 'screen1'
        Screen:
            name: 'screen1'
            Button:
                on_press:
                    manager.current = 'home_screen'
```

Comment: Do you, get any errors? Or what's the expected behavior vs what are you experiencing? I'm a bit confused reading this. I get that you're using Kivy and that you're missing a lot of handling in your .py file. But what exactly?

Comment: @Torxed, thank you for trying to answer my question! Inclement answered my question spot on. I'm sorry that I didn't include more code. Much of it was superfluous, as I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've been trying Runner().ids.manager.current = 'some_screen' in the .py file but it doesn't work. There isn't even an error thrown. The screen doesn't change at all.

It works fine, it just doesn't do what you believe. When you write `Runner()` you get a *new* instance of the Runner class, with its own children including its own ScreenManager. This one has nothing to do with the one you're displaying in your gui. When you set its `current` property the ScreenManager will dutifully change the screen, it's just you have no way to see that.

What you actually want is to change the `current` property of the widget that you are displaying in your gui. The best way to do this depends on the context, which you have omitted (always try to provide a full runnable example, it isn't clear what your failing code looked like). However, in this case the Runner instance is your root widget which is accessible with `App.get_running_app().root`, so you can write `App.get_running_app().root.ids.manager.current = 'some_screen'`. Again, there might be neater ways to do it depending on how you structure your code, but this is always an option.

Comment: yes! That's exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Thank you so much. The code makes sense and is neat to me because I sometimes use a similar string of commands. But I never used `get_running_app().root` so that'll be amazingly helpful to add to my Kivy coding repertoire!